# HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http

muchas gracias de antemano, este problema es un poco complicado:

Estoy en un proyecto que necesito hacer api calls a otro proyecto, sobre el que tengo absoluto control también.

En mi llamada api paso un parámetro que es una dirección de correo electrónico, nada muy complicado.

Lo testeo con test@test.com (email ficticio) y funciona, pero si meto demo+test@test.com no funciona, así que el error está relacionado con cómo paso este parámetro. De hecho ni siquiera alcanza mi segunda api, se bloquea, cuando lo único que cambia es un parámetro, el email.

Esto es lo que me sale por pantalla si intento acceder con esta dirección de email en el browser:

> HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found The request filtering module is
> configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.
>
> Most likely causes: The request contained a double escape sequence and
> request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny double
> escape sequences.
>
> Things you can try: Verify the
> configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering@allowDoubleEscaping
> setting in the applicationhost.config or web.confg file.
>
> Detailed Error Information: Module       RequestFilteringModule
> Notification     BeginRequest Handler    aspNetCore Error Code
> 0x00000000
>
> Requested URL    ............. Physical Path     ......... Logon
> Method       Not yet determined Logon User       Not yet determined
>
> More Information: This is a security feature. Do not change this
> feature unless the scope of the change is fully understood. You should
> take a network trace before changing this value to confirm that the
> request is not malicious. If double escape sequences are allowed by
> the server, modify the
> configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering@allowDoubleEscaping
> setting. This could be caused by a malformed URL sent to the server by
> a malicious user. View more information »

Yo pensé que codificando el parámetro podría escapar esto, pero no es así, alguien puede explicar por qué?

así es como lo hago:

```
            emailAddress = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(emailAddress);
            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($".../{emailAddress}");
```

Por cierto, si clickeo en mas informacion no se encuentra la pagina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionarlo, hay que cambiar un setting en webconfig,y permitir que se permita esto. No he encontrado otra manera de resolverlo:

```
<security>
<requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
</security>
```

Más información en: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/urls-that-containing-a-plus-symbol-can-t-be-displayed-370704515.html